# app scripts data validation from another workbook

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to validate cells based on a list from a different sheet in a separate workbook. I tested it by copying the desired sheet into the current workbook, to build the code. I changed all the references to reflect the actual source I wanted and everything seemed fine. when I deleted the copy I then had issues as it seems the data validation was still using the copy even though all the references were changed to the original source.

```
var DbSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ingredientDbBookUrl).getSheetByName(ingredientDbBookName);
function nameValidation(){
  var cell = sheet.getRange(3,nameColumn,recipe.getLastRow(),1);
  var list = DbSheet.getRange(3,2,ingredientDbSheet.getLastRow());
  var helpText = 'helptxt';
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInRange(list)
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.setHelpText(helpText)
.build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

is it possible to validate cells from a list in a separate workbook? does the fact that I'm using a bounded script matter?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with this:

```
function validatefromanothersheet() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Another ssid");
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const list=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  let rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,10,1).setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to validate cells from a list in a separate workbook?

Yes

> Does the fact that I'm using a bounded script matter?

No

#### Why did the validation have errors?

This is likely because once you have "set" the validation on a cell, it doesn't matter what the code is that was used to generate it.

It is like building something from a plan, and then expecting the building to change because you have changed the plan.

**You would need to first clear the rule and then build the rule and apply it again with the new source.**

Just probably best to not use [requireValueInRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range)) as the ranges may get crossed over. But if you are converting it to values as your code demonstrates said above, then it should be no issue.

#### Ref

- [DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Comment: my issue was the requireValueInRange. as some validations have more than the max allowed values for requireValueInList.
I'm not sure I understand what you mean by getting my ranges crossed over. Could you explain further?
Also, is there a workaround?